# Is there a way that i can find a field that does not contains the value of another field in access?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a link table dbo_Contacts,
there are fields of First_Name, Last_Name, Full_Name, and Title.

The problem here is that;

In field Full_Name; there has been mixed with Title.

So, I want to know if there is a way to check IF there is no contains of First_Name in Full_Name.

For example, the full name that contains job title which is not related to any first name or last name.

[This is the image example i need to check if the field full name does not contain any value of First_Name and Last_Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLS7g.png)

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the sample data it seems that you want to find the records if `full name = concat of first and last name` separated by space then you can use the concat operator `&` as follows:

```
select * from your_table where fullname = FirstName & " " & LastName
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but im not looking for full name that is complete. I'm looking for the full name that do not have their name in it

Comment: so you need not like as `select * from your_table where fullname not like FirstName & "*"`

Comment: i did it already. but when i run it there are still fullname that contains first name